# Oracle PL/SQL How to Get All Rows When the Date Parameter is Null?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This is where statement of my query:

```
   WHERE     date_column LIKE
                (CASE
                    WHEN :date_parameter IS NOT NULL
                    THEN
                        :date_parameter
                    ELSE '%%'  
                 END)
                 ...
```

If the parameter is null, I want to get all rows. How can I do this?

Comment: `LIKE` is for string (character values), it's not intended for DATE values. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Ok, even without "LIKE" when the parameter is null, I want to get all records. How can I do it in this case when statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE (:date_parameter is null
       OR date_column = :date_parameter)
```

I used to write

```
WHERE date_column = nvl(:date_parameter,date_column)
```

But I think people find it confusing to read.

Answer (score -1):

This should be work:

WHERE (date_column = :date_parameter AND :date_parameter IS NOT NULL) OR :date_parameter IS NULL